# .bash_profile won't open

Tags: bash, macos, chmod

When I run `open .bash_profile` a new terminal opens and

```
Last login: Wed Nov 30 19:01:22 on ttys004
/Users/MyName/.bash_profile ; exit;
➜  ~ /Users/MyName/.bash_profile ; exit;

[Process completed]
```

My permissions are

```
-rwxr-xr-x@    1 MyName  staff       639 Nov 30 19:02 .bash_profile
```

Also, when I run `ls -la`, `.bash_profile` is colored red. I don't know why. It wasn't like that before.

All I was trying to do was create an alias, but now I can't even open my `.bash_profile`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**tl;dr**

To ensure that you open a file in your default *text editor* using the macOS `open` CLI, use:

```
open -t ~/.bash_profile
```

Otherwise, if the file needn't be *excecutable*, run `chmod -x <file>` (`chmod -x ~/.bash_profile`, in this case) to make `open` behave like it did before.

---

From you question I infer that you're on macOS (OS X).

What the macOS `open` CLI does when passed a file depends on the file's suffix (extension), and, in the absence of one, on whether the file has the *executable* (`r`) permissions bit(s) set (if not, the file opens in the standard text editor, which is what you saw before).

A file displaying in *red* when you use `ls -a` (the `-a` being necessary to show hidden items such as `.bash_profile`), implies that the file is indeed executable by you.

A suffix-less *executable* (text) file causes `open` to run it in a new terminal window as a *shell script*, which is what you're seeing.

In other words: at some point, unbeknownst to you, executable permissions were assigned to `~/.bash_profile`, which explains the change in behavior.

However, there is no *need* for `~/.bash_profile` to be executable, because it is *sourced* by Bash on startup.

As stated above, either remove the executable permissions, or simply use `open -t` to open it.